# Kiu el la esprimoj “abomeni” kaj “malami” estas la plej forta?

Tags: word-usage

Kiu vorto inter *abomeni* kaj *malami* estas la plej forta (laŭ malŝateco)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nu, la [difino de "abomeni" en PIV](http://vortaro.net/#abomeni) estas "malam**eg**i pro fizike naŭzaj ecoj; pro morale tre malplaĉaj ecoj", do ŝajnas ke ĝi estas pli "forta" ol malami. La anglaj tradukoj konfirmas tion al mi ("to loathe, abhor" vs "to hate").